# CSS - Create a Tinted After Overlay on a single div container

Tags: css

It's it possible today to do a transparent color overlay process on a single div?  for example if I have the following HTML code

```
<div class="flower">
</div>
```

and I have the following html...

```
.flower { 
  width:320px; 
  height:240px; 
  background: url(img/flower.png) no-repeat; 
  border:5px solid #000000; 
 } 
  .flower:after { 
  background:#FF2400; opacity:0; 
  } 

  .flower:after:hover { 
  opacity:0.7; 
   }
```

So when someone hovers over this, they see a tinted red flower. Can we do something like this today with a single div?

Comment: In addition to what Paulie_D said, you also need to declare `.flower:hover:after` instead and add `.flower:after { content:""; }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least 2 methods of doing this.

**Method 1.**

*Overlay the whole div.*

NB.This will also affect any **content** that may be inside the div.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-4.jpg);
}
.overlay:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:hover:after {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="box overlay">
</div>
```

**Method 2.**

Since you are using a background image, we can add another background image on top of the first by way of a linear gradient with a single color and RGBA properties.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.bgimage {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-3.jpg);
}
.bgimage:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-3.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box bgimage">
</div>
```

This has the advantage of not affecting the content of the div.

I'm sure there are other methods but these are the first two that came to mind.